# Comma usage before "in which"

Tags: punctuation, relative-clauses

I came through a sentence that comma precedes "in which," but I have heard that no comma precedes "which" that has a preposition before it.

> Application of Hennig’s winnow therefore supported a different cladogram ***, in which*** tarantulas and their allies (Mygalomorphae) are more closely related to typical spiders (Araneomorphae) than they are to the Liphistiidae.

In the above sentence, is comma necessary ?

Comment: But if you are going to use a comma, the convention is not to put a space between it and the word that precedes it.  *...cladogram, in which...*

Comment: It is just a typo.

Comment: You also put a space before your question mark. The same convention applies there too. If you're going to worry about such stuff, might as well get it right.

Comment: Edit your answer and fix your typos–especially if you've made a typo in the exact thing you're asking about.

Comment: Also, please provide a link to where you found this sentence. The context could show whether a comma is necessary or not, since this could be a restrictive or non-restrictive relative clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking no comma is required. But because there are two fairly long clauses to the sentence, a comma between them provides a convenient separator. It does not change the meaning and is not absolutely necessary, but it makes the long sentence simpler to parse and therefore the meaning is easier to understand.

Comment: So are you saying that this rule applies only here or  all cases of "in which"?

Comment: There is no rule that says you must or must not use a comma before *in which*.

Comment: So what should I follow?